# Draw bar-charts with value_counts() for multiple columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to draw bar-charts with counts of unique values for all columns in a Pandas DataFrame. Kind of what `df.hist()` does for numerical columns, but I have categorical columns.

- I'd prefer to use the object-oriented approach, because if feels more natural and explicit to me.
- I'd like to have multiple Axes (subplots) within a single Figure, in a grid fashion (again like what `df.hist()` does).

My solution below does exactly what I want, but it feels cumbersome. I doubt whether I really need the direct dependency on Matplotlib (and all the code for creating the Figure, removing the unused Axes etc.). I see that [pandas.Series.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) has parameters `subplots` and `layout` which seem to point to what I want, but maybe I'm totally off here. I tried looping over the columns in my DataFrame and apply these parameters, but I cannot figure it out.

**Does anyone know a more compact way to do what I'm trying to achieve?**

```
# Defining the grid-dimensions of the Axes in the Matplotlib Figure
nr_of_plots = len(ames_train_categorical.columns)
nr_of_plots_per_row = 4
nr_of_rows = math.ceil(nr_of_plots / nr_of_plots_per_row)

# Defining the Matplotlib Figure and Axes
figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nr_of_rows, ncols=nr_of_plots_per_row, figsize=(25, 50))
figure.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

# Plotting on the Axes
i, j = 0, 0
for column_name in ames_train_categorical:
    if ames_train_categorical[column_name].nunique() <= 30:
        axes[i][j].set_title(column_name)
        ames_train_categorical[column_name].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[i][j])
        j += 1
        if j % nr_of_plots_per_row == 0:
            i += 1
            j = 0

# Cleaning up unused Axes
# plt.subplots creates a square grid of Axes. On the last row, not all Axes will always be used. Unused Axes are removed here.
axes_flattened = axes.flatten()
for ax in axes_flattened:
    if not ax.has_data():
        ax.remove()
```

**Edit: alternative idea**
Using the pyplot/state-machine WoW, you could do it like this with very limited lines of code. But this also has the downside that every graph gets it's own figure, you they're not nicely arranged in a grid.

```
for column_name in ames_train_categorical:
    ames_train_categorical[column_name].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
    plt.show()
```

**Desired output**
[image: desired output]

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "MS Zoning": ["RL", "FV", "RL", "RH", "RL", "RL"],
        "Street": ["Pave", "Pave", "Pave", "Grvl", "Pave", "Pave"],
        "Alley": ["Grvl", "Grvl", "Grvl", "Grvl", "Pave", "Pave"],
        "Utilities": ["AllPub", "NoSewr", "AllPub", "AllPub", "NoSewr", "AllPub"],
        "Land Slope": ["Gtl", "Mod", "Sev", "Mod", "Sev", "Sev"],
    }
)
```

Here is a bit more idiomatic way to do it:

```py
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

size = math.ceil(df.shape[1]** (1/2))
fig = plt.figure()

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    fig.add_subplot(size, size, i + 1)
    df[col].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=plt.gca(), title=col, rot=0)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me. I see you know the dataset I'm practicing with as well. :-) I see how your solution is more compact, but conceptually it's kind of similar (create the fig, add the plots, remove the unused axes). I kind of hoped that with the Pandas plot function I could be done even more compact, without depending on Matplotlib directly.

Comment: I added a very short alternative to the description using the state-machine approach. I was just wondering if something like this would be possible using an OO approach, and moreover getting my plots in a single figure in a grid-fashion.

Comment: Right. I don't know if your expectations can be fully satisfied, but I've updated my answer to get the same result (grid plot) while compacting the code even more (no list comprehensions anymore, no ax.remove, etc.). Cheers